# Can someone tell me what is the Azure DevOps server installation disk space?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, server, devops

Can someone tell me what is the Azure DevOps server installation disk space?

I need to find out if I have enough space for an Azure DevOps server and azure pipelines

Comment: Hi @Dehanys, does the following answers resolve your puzzle? Or whether could you tell us your specific issue or concerns about the Azure DevOps server installation disk space? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Dehanys, how are things going? Have you already got what you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends your usage.

> For example, if a repository has 50 GB within it's main branch and 200
> GB of history, we recommend 800 GB of SSD-based
> storage

Check minimum requirements for Azure DevOps server on
Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops-2022